# Modifying url param in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Is there any way to change a parameter in a url request on load?

My route basically checks for a language in the url `http://localhost/<language>/<controller>`

However the problem is that if a random text is inserted in the language parameter, it then loads the default text which the way I set up the translation files will output things like `menu.home`

Is there anyway for a controller to redirect to a url with the default language?
for example `http://localhost/fakeLanguage/home` will redirect to `http://localhost/en/home` and `http://localhost/fakeLanguage/about` redirects to `http://localhost/en/about`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Route must filter segments with regex, something like this:

```
// load available language names from config
$langs = Kohana::$config->load('lang.available');
Route::set('lang_route', '<language>/<controller>', array('language' => '('.implode('|', $langs).')'))
    ->defaults(...);
```

Or use [route filters](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#route-filters), which can easily modify route segment values.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for thanks! the only problem I had was that the '['.implode('|', $langs).']' had to be '('.implode('|', $langs).')'

Answer (score 0):

While this is only a rough idea of one possible solution, you may want to consider defining an array of all the supported languages. Something like this:

```
<?php
/*
    Part 1 - Create an array of all the known languages. Consider making this part of the application configuration file.
*/
$languages = array(
    "en",
    "ge",
    "pirate"
);
?>
```

And then check against that array within the controller file. Perhaps using the controller's before method:

```
<?php
/*
    Part 2 - In the controller file add a before method that checks to see if the requested language exists.
*/
public function before(){
    if(!in_array($this->request->param('langauge'),$languages)):
        // If the language is unknown perform a redirect.
        url::redirect('DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_URL');
    endif;
}
?>
```

Converting the first segment of the URL structure above can be done with code like:

```
<?php
    // Get the current URI
    $url = $this->request->detect_uri();

    // Get the query string
    // Note: If you aren't interested in preserving the query string this next line can be removed.
    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != '') $url .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    // Set the default language. Consider setting this in your application configuration file instead.
    $defaultLanguage = 'pirate';

    // Replace the first URI segment with the default language.
    $redirectURL = preg_replace("/^\/.*?(\/.*)$/",("/{$defaultLanguage}$1"),$url,1);
?>
```

Comment: I completely forgot that there was a before method. thanks for pointing that out. this is basically what I'm doing right now. thanks for that :)

Comment: I still have the problem of figuring out how to change only one portion of the uri

Comment: Are your URLs consistent enough for you to lean on convention? If so running a RegEx replace on the path might do the trick. Maybe something with a pattern like "\^/.*?(/.*)$\" and a replace string of "/en$1"?

Comment: Yeah they're consistent enough, the language parameter always comes first in all routes, I'll try that thanks